# iOS 7 UITextView select word or image

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsdatadetector

I have a UITextView in iOS 7 using attributed text.  The raw text being parsed before putting into the UITextView looks something like this.

"Welcome to my example @(John Doe)(johndoeid) @(Jane Doe)(janedoeid)"

When I parse this text and put it in the UITextView it looks like this.

"Welcome to my example **John Doe**  **Jane Doe**"

My question is this.

When I click on John Doe or Jane Doe in the textview, how can I get the ID for the user "johndoe" or "janedoe" so I can take an action on that?   I was thinking store off the original location and the new location and use that but that seems clunky.

Answer (score 1):

You add custom attributes to the text assuming you are using `NSAttributedString`.  Take a look at this link below to see examples of how to search for a specific attribute associated with text.

None of the examples will actually create custom attributes but you can see how we search for every font attribute and change the font size.  You would be able to so something similar once you attach a custom attribute.  If you get stuck let me know and I can try hack something more specific for you.

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/implementing-rich-text-with-images-on-os-x-and-ios/

Specifically look in the `OSTextView.m` source listing file for the `resizeText` method. Here is some of the code to search for the NSFont attribute

```
[self.textStorage enumerateAttributesInRange:rangeAll options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:
 ^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

     // Iterate over each attribute and look for a Font Size
     [attributes enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
         if ([[key description] isEqualToString:@"NSFont"]) {
             UIFont *font = obj;
             float fontSize = font.pointSize + bySize;
             smallestFontSize = MIN(smallestFontSize, fontSize);
             largestFontSize = MAX(largestFontSize, fontSize);
         }

     }];
 }];
```

Further down in the method is the code to replace the NSFont attribute, in your case you could just add your custom attribute - note that we first copy the existing attributes and then add to them as you may not want to remove any existing attributes.

```
[self.textStorage enumerateAttributesInRange:rangeAll options:NSAttributedStringEnumerationLongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired usingBlock:
 ^(NSDictionary *attributes, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

     NSMutableDictionary *mutableAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:attributes];

     // Iterate over each attribute and look for a Font Size
     [mutableAttributes enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {

         if ([[key description] isEqualToString:@"NSFont"]) {

             UIFont *font = obj;
             float fontSize = font.pointSize;
             fontSize += bySize;
             fontSize = MIN(fontSize, MAXFONTSIZE);

             // Get a new font with the same attributes and the new size
             UIFont *newFont = [font fontWithSize:fontSize];

             // Replace the attributes, this overrides whatever is already there
             [mutableAttributes setObject:newFont forKey:key];
         }

     }];

     // Now replace the attributes in ourself (UITextView subclass)
     [self.textStorage setAttributes:mutableAttributes range:range];
 }];
```

Now your custom attribute is neatly embedded in the attributed string and you should be able to archive it and unarchive it without loosing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it makes the most sense to store all of your locations in a `NSDictionary`, and do a lookup in that data structure.

I know it seems clunky, but that's really your only option.